# Shell script the extract only the IP addresses from a line

Tags: shell, scripting

Using bash script I would like to extract only the IP addresses from the below

proxy-list="101.21.60.111:4666,101.21.60.112:4666

Comment: `I would like to extract only the IP addresses from the below` -- ok, go ahead.

Comment: What have you tried this far? Why what you've tried does not work? Try to come up with some concrete script/code in your question. SO is not a programming service as some people say, so you should come up with something on your own which may then be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `egrep -o`:

```
> s='proxy-list="101.21.60.111:4666,101.21.60.112:4666"'
> egrep -o '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' <<< "$s"
101.21.60.111
101.21.60.112
```

OR else:

```
> egrep -o '([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+' <<< "$s"
101.21.60.111
101.21.60.112
```

Comment: Nice one! I am guessing if it is possible to do something like `egrep -o '[0-9]+\.{3}[0-9]+`. Tried but didn't work to me.

Comment: Actually `egrep -o '([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+' <<< "$s"` will work.